# Are interceptors in Struts 2 the same as interceptors in Java Spring 3?

Tags: spring-mvc, struts

I am new to Web Development. I am learning Java Spring. I found a good online tutorial for interceptors in Struts 2. My question is, are interceptors in Struts 2 the same as interceptors in Java Spring? If not, what are the differences? If they are different, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that this is not a differentiator in choosing between Spring MVC ( if that's what you mean by Java Spring ) and Struts2.  The interceptors in both frameworks play the same architecural role by isolating cross cutting concerns from your core business logic classes.

At least in Struts 2, it's fairly uncommon to code against the interceptor api; <5% of your total development time.  This would suggest that you would only really care about the differences in the interceptor api's if you had some particular use case that you felt would be solved by interceptors, and then this use case could help you evaluate the two api's.

If you don't have such a use case, which seems likely if you are new to web app development, I recommend not putting to much into this topic; either framework will most likely server you well.  Though there could be other valid reasons for choosing one or the other.

Comment: If I learn interceptors in Struts 2, will it be beneficial for Java Spring training?

Comment: I don't think it's uncommon to write interceptors at all in S2 apps; I don't think I've done an S2 or Spring app where I haven't used them. They're very common, and very useful.

Comment: Interceptors are a common design pattern, if you learn them anywhere that knowledge transfers to all other applications of the pattern.  That is the central benefit of writing software according to patterns. I'm not sure what you mean by Java Spring training?  Are you talking about some certification?

Comment: @Dave It's not uncommon in the sense that you dont do it.  But it is uncommon as a percentage of the total code you do to implement a site on S2, wouldn't you say?  And this leads me to think that it's not a deciding metric of which framework to use . . .

Comment: @chad As a percentage of "total application code", of course it's substantially less--that kind of goes without saying, pretty much by definition. As long as whatever framework under discussion provides cross-app behavioral capabilities, no, it wouldn't make sense to use it as a large metric, although the ease of which such a thing can be implemented must be taken into consideration.

Comment: @Dave  I totally agree.  That's why I think this decision can't be made without some specific use cases.  I'm probably venting from work here . . . technologies chosen and architectures designed before use cases considered . . . castles made of sand, arg!

Comment: Do you think this question deserves a -1?

Comment: @CodeBlue . . . I didn't vote the question down myself, but I think the vote is probably based upon the fact that it's not really an answerable question . . . you actually need requirements to make a choice like this.  Perhaps you only requirement is that you need a webapp platform to experiment with?  But that's just me guessing.